# Estimating the slope of the an exponential growth

Tags: euclidean-geometry, graphing-functions, slope

I want to estimate the slope of the following exponential growth

[image]

The simplest way I see is to assume that the exponential growth can be approximated with a straight line. Then we write down a right triangle with opposite leg $10^{-2}$ and contiguous leg of $1$. Assuming a small angle we get

$$\tan \alpha \approx \alpha = 10^{-2}$$

So the approximate slope is $\tan \alpha \approx \alpha = 10^{-2}$.

Is there a simpler method to get an approximation of the slope?

Comment: This looks to be of the form $U=10^{-6} (1-e^{-kt})$ where $k$ is the rate constant. Is it not $k$ you really want? If it is, satisfy yourself that $ln(1-10^{6} U) = -kt$ and plot the values of $ln(1-10^{6} U)$ against $t$. You should see a straight line going (approximately) through the origin which will have slope $-k$.

Comment: It looks like $\log_{10} U=A-B \exp(-kt)$, where $A\approx -6$, $B\approx 3$, $k\approx 2$.

Comment: You should write what part of displayed curve you want to describe. For initial part of curve slope of $\log_{10} U$ is about $2/1=2$ if you take $\Delta t=1$ (triangle formed by tangent in rectangle formed by $t=0$, $t=1$, $U=10^{-6}$ and $U=10^{-8}$) and about $0.4/0.1=4$ if you take $\Delta t=0.1$ (small triangle down from $10^{-8}$ line).